# algebraic group to the lie algebra and hom

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras

Let $G$ be a linear algebraic group and let $\rho:G \rightarrow GL(V_{1})$ and $\psi:G \rightarrow GL(V_{2})$ be finite representations. Why is $Hom_{G}(V_{1},V_{2}) \subset Hom_{\mathfrak G}(V_{1},V_{2})$, where $\mathfrak G$ is the Lie algebra of $G$?

Comment: Your title does not make a lot of sense!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because a representation of the group induces a representation of the Lie algebra of the group on the same vector space, and an homomorphism of representations of a group is automatically an homomorphism for the associated Lie algebra representations.

This is immediate in the case of Lie groups. If $\rho:G\to\mathrm{GL}(V)$ is a homomorphism of Lie groups, turning $V$ into a representation of $G$, then we can take the differential $d\rho:\mathfrak{g}=T_eG\to T_e\mathrm{GL}(V)=\mathfrak{gl}(V)$, which is automatically a Lie algebra homomorphism, and this turns $V$ into a $\mathfrak{g}$-module.

The algebraic group version of this is exactly the same, *mutatis mutandi*.

Comment: te llego el mail?

Comment: Sipi. Está en mi lista de cosas para leer :)

Comment: @Meriano Ok. Tiene una pequeña errata que puedo corregir si queres, pero no cambia mucho. Tengo tiempo?

Comment: thank you! why are the two homs not equal then? perhaps I misunderstood something.

Comment: @Rkoustach, If $G$ is a Lie group of dimension *zero*, then the Lie algebra does not see anything... More generally, the Lie algebra can only see what happens in the connected component of the identity.